# MAVEN build Error, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2 & unable to find main class

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans-8

I'm suddenly getting a build error using Maven to build a JavaFX application that utilizes com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind, I haven't updated the POM for about 3-4 weeks, therefore Im perplexed as to why this suddenly occurred.

**The entire error message is:**

The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

The artifact org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2 has been relocated to commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2

**I updated the com.fasterxml.jackson.core & commons-io, now when building I get:**

The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

**When I run the application from NetBeans I get:**

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Video_Assembler ---
Error: Could not find or load main class com.conuretech.video_assembler.MainApp

**Here is my POM.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.conuretech</groupId>
    <artifactId>Video_Assembler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Video_Assembler_v1</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- For testing <mainClass>com.conuretech.test.test</mainClass>-->
       <mainClass>com.conuretech.video_assembler.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>
    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>conuretech</name>
    </organization>
    <repositories>
   <repository>
   <id>xuggle repo</id>
   <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
      <!-- apache commons io 
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>-->
<!-- updated due to previous error-->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
      <!-- amazon aws start-->
      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.27</version>
</dependency>  
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
      <!-- amazon aws end-->
<!-- xuggler start -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.4</version>
  </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
      <artifactId>xuggle-utils</artifactId>
      <version>1.22</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- xuggler end-->
    <!-- dropbox core api -->
    <!--
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>[1.7,1.8)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
    <version>8.20.8</version>
</dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjfx-dialogs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <tasks>
                            <echo>***BASE DIRECTORY ${project.basedir}</echo>
                        </tasks>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                     <fork>true</fork>
          <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
          <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Im not sure how to further resolve the "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.2" issue and I have already declared main class using `<mainClass>com.conuretech.video_assembler.MainApp</mainClass>`, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should enable debug logging for more details?

Comment: Well the maven is issued via NetBeans, I had to issue `mvn -X -e exec:exec` myself via command line ,and I got an even more cryptic **message**: "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (d
efault-cli) on project Video_Assembler: Command execution failed. Process exited
 with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec
embler: Command execution failed." This is a `MojoExecutionException` so i have lost my mojo! but whats the solution???